# JPQL query with WHERE on nested fields

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql, named-query

I have a java entity class UserBean with a list of events:

```
@OneToMany
private List<EventBean> events;
```

EventBean has Date variable:

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date eventDate;
```

Now in UserBean I want to create a NamedQuery that returns all dates that fall within a specific range:

```
@NamedQuery(name="User.findEventsWithinDates",
            query="SELECT u.events FROM UserBean u WHERE u.name = :name AND u.events.eventDate > :startDate AND u.events.eventDate < :endDate")
```

The above query does not compile though. I get this error:

```
The state field path 'u.events.eventDate' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

By the way, I use EclipseLink version 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b.

What can I do to make this query work? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Path `u.events.eventDate` is an illegal construct in JPQL, because it is not allowed to navigate via a collection valued path expression. In this case `u.events` is a collection valued path expression. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> It is syntactically illegal to compose a path expression from a path
>   expression that evaluates to a collection. For example, if o
>   designates Order, the path expression o.lineItems.product is illegal
>   since navigation to lineItems results in a collection. This case
>   should produce an error when the query string is verified. To handle
>   such a navigation, an identification variable must be declared in the
>   FROM clause to range over the elements of the lineItems collection.

This problem can be solved by using JOIN:

```
SELECT distinct(u) 
FROM UserBean u JOIN u.events e 
WHERE u.name = :someName
      AND e.eventDate > :startDate 
      AND e.eventDate < :endDate
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I only want to select s user with a specific name though. So I thought if I add 'WHERE u.name = :name' before the JOIN statement would do just that. I get this error though:
The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
What would be a valid conditional expression to select a user by name?

Comment: Added :name to answer. Such a condition goes to existing WHERE clause - additional WHERE clauses before JOIN statement are not possible.

Comment: Yay, that did it. The final query:
SELECT DISTINCT u.events
FROM UserBean u JOIN u.events e
WHERE u.name = :name
     AND e.eventDate > :startDate 
     AND e.eventDate < :endDate
Thanks a lot for your help. I'm quite new to JPA, is this the most efficient way to retrieve the data I need from the database? The query seems to be slow to execute, but my sometimes slow internet connection might be the reason for that.

Comment: Why is the distinct needed here?